# How should I separate integration tests for an EF code first DAL and pure unit tests of the DAL clients?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, ef-code-first, integration-testing, entity-framework-5

Having seen some strong advice against testing EF against mocks, especially Code First, I have decided to go with integration testing against a SqlCe database dedicated to testing, and then use pure unit tests further downstream from the unit of work and repositories provided by DbContext and DbSet.

I am just unclear where to draw the line and what to test where. I know I can mock the DAL in my service layer when I am confident the DAL specific integration tests cover its insides, but what do I test in the DAL? There doesn't seem to be much point testing to see if I can save and read an object, because EF is external and already tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will test your mapping and queries in DAL by using integration tests. Example:

```
public class Service {
   private readonly IDAL _dal;

   public Service(IDAL dal) {
       // Not null validation here
       _dal = dal;
   }

   public void DoSomething() {
       SomeData data = FindSomeData();
       // Do some logic
       _dal.Commit();
   }

   protected virtual SomeData FindSomeData() {
       return _dal.SomeData.Where(...).FirstOrDefault();
   }
}
```

This is very simplified example showing:

- `Service` dependent on `DAL`. `DAL` interface is passed through constructor injection.
- The `Service` contains public DoSomething method you want to test to know if the logic is executed correctly. But this method is also dependent on DB query and DB persistence (`Commit`).
- The query is part of your logic but executing such query is separate concern so it is handled by its own method. In more complex situation this method can be in other class injected to the `Service` class (repository). The key criteria for these query methods are:

  - They don't return `IQueryable`
  - They don't accept `Expression<>` as parameters

How to unit test `DoSomething` method:

- In this simple example your test class will derive from `Service` class and override `FindSomeData` to return test data. In case of injection you would instead define fake for injected class.
- You will also mock `IDAL` and you can verify that `Commit` was called

What integration test you should use:

- You should create test for `FindSomeData` querying the real database
- In general you should also have integration test for `Commit` but it is more difficult to achieve because the example has commit called directly from `DoSomething`. You don't want to test that method again and in the same time `Commit` method has too much generic cases because it simply flushes all changes from current context to database. I usually have separate tests for inserting, updating and deleting every entity type. When the `DoSomething` method does some complex modification you can split the method into two methods one handled by unit test for a real logic and second covered by integration tests for different persistence scenarios which can be produced by your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is tested, but your DAL, especially mapping, is not. I prefer having integration tests to show me that at the very least my mapping is right, and better yet, that I can successfully perform all CRUD operations against my database.

Comment: could you elaborate a little on testing my mapping? Things like ID being incremented, required fields, FK's, etc?

Comment: @ProfK No. Mapping is relation between properties in your model and columns in your database. If something is wrong (i.e. column renamed, property renamed, convention dropped, anything else), you'll get runtime error. You should check all those things in your integration tests - at least by trying to read and materialize a sample set of your data.

Comment: But to test if my Surname value is stored in a Surname column would require tests too complex for what I need. I trust EF to map columns as expected by convention.

Comment: @ProfK Nope. Test is as simple as `context.Set<Person>().Take(sampleSize).ToArray()`. If it maps, it works. If it doesn't, it throws an exception. You can add more checks to see if your complex entity is mapped as expected. You can trust EF to map your columns by convention, but you can't trust your code and database to be always in sync.

Answer (score 0):

What we usually test DB-wise, is if the complex object graphs can be properly inserted, updated, deleted; basically testing the more complex mappings.
In my opinion there's not really much point in testing if an object with 3 primitive value properties can be inserted and whatnot, because then you'd never see the end of it.
We kind of favor being optimistic (that the simple stuff will just work), we test the more complex associations, and if we encounter an error in our mapping (e.g. an object that should be deleted but isn't) we write an extra test for that.
It's usually not wise to test absolutely everything from a business perspective; you should focus on the high-risk/high-damage stuff first and then work your way down the severity ladder until you think it's not worth it anymore.

Comment: Except in a TDD scenario all code should be written to pass a test, and I'm trying to move into a TDD method.

Answer (score 0):

1) Have a set of integration tests which test your mappings

2) Make your DAL *very* light weight but with sufficent power to construct querys, something like:

```
public interface IDb
{
    IQueryable<T>Query<T>();
    ... (save, delete, get-by-id methods)...
}
```

3) Write objects which encapsulate the logic behind constructing the query against the DAL

```
public class MuppetSearch
{
    public MuppetColor? Color { get; set;}
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public IQueryable<Muppet> ConstructQuery(IDb db)
    {
        var query = db.Query<Muppet>();
        if(Color.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(m=>m.Value == Color.Value);
        }
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
        {
            query = query.Where(m=>m.Name.Contains(Name));
        }
        return query;
    }
}
```

4) Test those, mocking all the data you need should be pretty trivial

5) In your service use the search classes to do your query construction